# global space function inside a namespace

Tags: php

How can I declare the bellow function in the global space?

```
namespace something\else;

function example() {
  #some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php):

> To combine global non-namespaced code with namespaced code, only bracketed syntax is supported.

So if you have full control to the PHP file, try

```
namespace Something {
    function example() {
    }
}
namespace {
    function example() {
    }
}
```